# AddClass to an image when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, addclass

I have an `<img>` tag which already has the `icon` class.

I need to add two extra classes to that element for [animate.css] (http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) animations.

Those extra classes, `flip` and `animated`, need to be added once the user scrolls to the image.

I tried a lot of different ways but none of them worked.
Here's the html:

```
<div class="col-md-12 ">
    <div class="box">
        <img src="img/world.png" class="icon"/>
        <h1>WEB<br/>DESIGN</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

The users should scroll down around 1328px so that the animations starts.

**Bottom line:** How do I add `flip` and `animated` classes to `<img>` when the user scrolls to it?

Comment: Please add the javascript code that failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMardell/rqgh699w/

I used the following "isScrolledIntoView" function from this post: [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height(),
        elemTop = $(elem).offset().top,
        elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if (isScrolledIntoView('.box')) {
        $('img').addClass('animated flip').css('background', 'red');
    }
});
```

It waits for your parent .box element to be visible in the window, then triggers

Comment: Unless the question is tagged with jQuery, don't post it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
window.onscroll = function() { 
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
  if(scrollTop > 1328) {
    //do what you want.
    alert(scrollTop);
  }
}
```

Is that what you needed?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [onscroll](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp) event listener and the [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop) property to wait until it's time to add those classes, something like:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 1328) {
        // add your classes
    }
}
```

You can use `.className` ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className)) to actually add the classes:

```
document.querySelectorAll("img.icon")[0].className += " animated flip";
//                                                     ^ note this space
```

[`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll) could just as easily be replaced with `.getElementsByClassName("icon")`.

If you need a one-time use animation, the above examples will be fine, it looks like this:

```
window.onscroll = function(){
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 1328){
        document.querySelectorAll("img.icon")[0].className += " flip animated";
    }
}
```

here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/theonlygusti/s25w1j3w/).

If you need the animation to trigger every time, check out [this well-commented JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/theonlygusti/s25w1j3w/1/)